# Remove version-specific xna tags

Tags: discussion, tags

XNA will never get past version 4, and version 3.1 *should* be unused (though [xna-3.1](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xna-3.1) has 3 questions this year, 5 total, somehow), I am of the opinion that [xna](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xna) and [xna-4.0](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xna-4.0) should be merged.  But I could not initiate the voting process:

[image]

Comment: Your question title and question body are at odds -- do you want to remove *all* version tags, merge XNA and XNA 4, or both?

Comment: I think [tag:xna-4.0] should be subsumed under [tag:xna].  [tag:xna-3.1] could stay or go.  Probably stay, since the few questions that use it seem to asking specifically about version differences.